# Cypress: Try/Catch block for External Services?

Tags: try-catch, cypress

So what I want to do might be impossible and actually may not even be recommended, but im curious of the best way to handle this.

Currently one of my applications attempts to use an external service (Specifically google maps API). Sometimes I get a bad response from googles API (or it times out). It's rare (less than 1/30 times maybe) but it still happens and introduces flakiness into the automation tests.

I thought about stubbing this out everytime, but that would also sort of I feel like "lower" the test value (Since google maps api is important in this case)

I was curious if Cypress is able to do something that would TRY to get a response (with a successful status code) and if it failed maybe leave a log note but allow the test to continue on (either via stubbing or just continuing on).

This may even be a bad idea as we don't really "know" from just looking at the results but I wanted to at least pose the question.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any merit in polling for a good good response? If it's one in thirty failure rate, a retry should probably succeed on 2nd or 3rd go.

Comment: Also curious as to what the effect is on the test - how does it fail. Is it an uncaught exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by [only conditionally sending mocked data,](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#res-send-shorthand) based on the response to that API call.

```js
cy.intercept('/foo', (req) => { // replace with the URL for the google API
  req.continue((res) => { // pass through the request to the real API
    if (res.statusCode !== 200) { // or whatever "success" statusCode/criteria is
      cy.log('my information I want to log')
      res.send(200, myMockedBody) // send the mocked response.
    }
    res.send(); // otherwise, just send the response from the API
  });
});
```